# Are global constants possible?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to declare global constants?  That is, constants that are available in all classes? When I try to declare a constant outside of a class, as I do with an enum, I get a parsing error.

I've been using enums this way for a while, but enums are restricted to integers, and I'd like to use easy-to-use words instead of float values.

Example; I'd like the following to be available in any class:

```
const float fast   = 1.5f;
const float normal = 1f; 
const float slow   = .75f;
```

I know i can work around this by creating an enum (Speed) for the speed names, then creating a static method `SpeedNum()` that reads enum `Speed` and `return`s an associated value, but it requires so much extra writing each time and I was hoping for something more elegant:

Ex:

```
public double function SpeedNum(Speed speed) 
{
    switch (speed)
    {
        case speed.fast:   return 1.5;
        case speed.normal: return 1f;
        case speed.slow:   return .75f;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use a static class with those static fields?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Create a static class e.g. called `Constants` containing the constants and access them using `Constants.MyConstant`.

```
public static class Constants
{
  public const string MyConstant = "Hello world";
  public const int TheAnswer = 42;
}

class Foo
{
  // ...

  private string DoStuff()
  {
    return Constants.MyConstant;
  }
}
```

To answer your implied question: You cannot declare constants outside of a class.

Comment: Thank you for this super detailed answer, including my implied question (which I should have asked outright)

Answer (score 26):

If you're targeting C# version 6 or higher, and you don't want to use the traditional "static_class_name.Thing", you may use [using static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static), introduced in C# 6.

```
// File 1
public static class Globals
{
    public const string bobsName = "bob!";
}

// File 2
using System;
using static Globals;

class BobFinder
{
    void Run() => Console.WriteLine(bobsName);
}
```

Syntactical sugar. But I find it nifty.

Comment: `using static` was an amazing addition to C#

Comment: and from C# 10 you can have a single `global using static Globals;` somewhere instead of needing it in every file .. (PS I would capitalize `bobsName`)

Comment: That's not nifty. That's SEXY.

Answer (score 3):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx) gives the answer to your question as to why you cant use it outside your class:

> The const keyword is used to modify a declaration of a field or local
>   variable.

So your field or local variable can be present within a class, this means you cannot have a global const

You can better create a Class with with only constants like this:

```
public static class GlobalConstant
{
    public const float fast = 1.5f;
    public const float normal = 1f; 
    public const float slow = .75f;
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
class MyProgram
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GlobalConstant.fast);
    }
}
```

Comment: i think you might need the "f" when you instantiate the float,or it might not compile.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it up by the `using` directive, and providing a static class within a namespace. Or outside if you want the properties truly global. This will allow you to make calls to public static members from the `Constants` class within the `RaceCars` namespace, without prepending them with `Constants` like `Constants.slow`, instead, it's just `slow`.

The static class:

```
namespace RaceCars
{
    public static class Constants
    {
        public static float slow = 0.5f;
    }
}
```

The calling of a 'constant':

```
namespace RaceCars
{
    using static Constants;
    
    internal class PickupTruck
    {
        private truckSpeed = slow;
    }
}
```